# SCA Solution in Large Distributed Control System

Tags: osgi, esb, sca

I want to provide a solution for building our large distributed control system. The current implementation is written in C++. I need to rewrite it again.

I have several questions:

1. The system should have hot-plugin feature, I don't know whether
   it exists some OSGi implementations to support C++ programming model
2. Which ESB could be better if consider real-time and flexible
   routing, since large volume messages will be transferred quickly
   between nodes?
3. Since integration is very important in our system, which MOM can
   be used to build my ESB according to real-time and flexible routing
   constraint?
4. Which open source SCA implementation is suitable for C++
   programming model?

Hope your answers eagerly!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you require a C++ runtime, I would look at Trentino (http://trentino.sourceforge.net/), which is sponsored by Siemens.

There are a number of Java=based runtimes. One that supports dynamic deployment of contributions is Fabric3 (www.fabric3.org).